# Nested generics compilation error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

How can I do something like this in Java? Now compiler says that V cannot be resolved.

Period.java

```
public interface Period<T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

Schule.java

```
public interface Schedule<T extends Period<V>> {
    List<T> getPeriods;

    V getValue(long timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Well `V` isn't a type parameter anywhere...

Comment: The first line should read `public interface Schedule<V,T extends Period<V>> {`. Although I have a sneaky suspicion that generics aren't the right answer here.

Comment: I agree with @biziclop. If generics is what you find fit for your needs, there's a chance you might want to use `?` instead of `V` (looks like `V` has no direct relation to class `Schedule`)

Comment: @biziclop, yes, this is what fixed the problem, thanks.